# React Redux unexpected key passed to create store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am getting the error `Unexpected key "characters" found in initialState argument passed to createStore. Expected to find one of the known reducer keys instead: "marvelReducer", "routing". Unexpected keys will be ignored.`

rootReducer :

```
 import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
 import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';
 import marvelReducer from './marvelReducer';

 const rootReducer = combineReducers({
   marvelReducer,
   routing: routerReducer
 });
 export default rootReducer;
```

marvelReducer :

```
import { FETCH_MARVEL } from '../constants/constants';
import objectAssign from 'object-assign';

export default function marvelReducer(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_MARVEL:
      return objectAssign({}, state, {characters: action.data});

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

store :

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import rootReducer from '../reducers/index';

const initialState = {
  characters: []
};

const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState);

export const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('../reducers/', () => {
    const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers/index').default;
    store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
  });
}

export default store;
```

I have very similar code in another application and it's working fine. Not sure what's going on here

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a small mismatch between what you set as the initial state of the store and what you tell the store to expect what the initial state of the store should be, e.g. - update your initial state setting for the store as such:

```
const initialState = {
   marvel: {
     characters: []
   }
};
```

And also it's a good idea to name your state tree variable holders to meaningful names that do not contain reducer in them, so update

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
   marvelReducer,
   routing: routerReducer
});
```

to

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
   marvel: marvelReducer,
   routing: routerReducer
});
```

And that should do the trick for you.

Hope this helps,

PS. some docs.

From [the docs](http://rackt.org/redux/docs/api/createStore.html):

> If you produced reducer with combineReducers, this must be a plain object with the same shape as the keys passed to it. Otherwise, you are free to pass anything that your reducer can understand.

If you don't need to handle any actions related to `one` or `two`, just pull them in initially, this could be as simple as

```
export default combineReducers({
  events,
  flash,
  one: (state = {}) => state,
  two: (state = {}) => state
})
```

Comment: setting the initial state as the same attribute name as the reducer, does that end up overriding the reducer?

Comment: @erichardson30 It does not - it will simply set up an initial state, it does not overwrite the reducer.

Here is a little more guidance from [the redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html)

`[initialState] (any): The initial state. You may optionally specify it to hydrate the state from the server in universal apps, or to restore a previously serialized user session. If you produced reducer with combineReducers, this must be a plain object with the same shape as the keys passed to it. Otherwise, you are free to pass anything that your reducer can understand.`

Comment: "There's a small mismatch between what you set as the initial state of the store and what you tell the store to expect what the initial state of the store should be"

I really can't follow this statement, can you elaborate a little clearer?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html) for `combineReducers`:

> The `combineReducers` helper function turns an object whose values are
>   different reducing functions into a single reducing function you can
>   pass to `createStore`.
>
> The resulting reducer calls every child reducer, and gathers their
>   results into a single state object. **The shape of the state object
>   matches the keys of the passed `reducers`**.

In short, your reducers are configured to handle a state in the form of

```
{
    marvelReducer,
    routing
}
```

But you are handing it an initial state in the form of

```
{
    characters
}
```

To fix this issue, you will either have to change the keys of the object you pass to `combineReducers` to include `characters`, or change the initial state to contain the keys that your reducers are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

To add to elod answer,
The store state object has different properties or different data sections:

```
{a:data,b:data,c:data}
```

When you combine reducers, you MUST map each property of the state object to a different reducer

```
{a:reducerOfDataA,b:reducerOfDataB,c:reducerOfDataC}
```

This is a mechanism in redux which enforces seperation of data concern for each reducer, reducerOfDataA cannot modify data of reducerOfDataB .
This means that all data of reducerOfDataA must sit under {a:...} and not be divided under different properties directly on the root state object {partA1:... , partA2 :...}

Took me entire night to figure this out, hope this little comment will save yours.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and I cannot follow the logic of any of these potential solutions.

The arguments to combineReducers are references to reducer objects, not state, keys. The key error is as cryptic as most other redux errors, and indeed most of the answers or potential solutions offered to them.

Comment: Can you post what your reducer/state looks like? What the answer is trying to explain is that if you have a root reducer that looks like 
`const rootReducer = combineReducers({
   marvel: marvelReducer,
   routing: routerReducer
});` 
then your state should contain a marvel object and a routing object with all the properties inside those