# Redux: Unexpected key found in preloadedState argument passed to createStore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Can you help me with exception `Unexpected key "userName" found in preloadedState argument passed to createStore. Expected to find one of the known reducer keys instead: "default". Unexpected keys will be ignored.`

I discovered this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37998706/4443351) but it doesn't help me. I don't undestand something, maybe this part from documentation: **plain object with the same shape as the keys passed to it**

Can you exlain me my mistake on my example?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import  App from './containers/App.jsx';
import * as reducers from './reducers'
import types from './constants/actions';

const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);

const destination = document.querySelector("#container");

var store = createStore(reducer, {
    userName : ''
});


ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>,
    destination
);

console.log(1)

store.subscribe( ()=> {
console.log("-------------------------")
let s = store.getState()
console.log("STATE = " + s)
for (var k in s) {
    if (s.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        console.log("k = " + k + "; value = " + s[k]);
    }
}
})

store.dispatch({
        type: types.LOAD_USER_NAME,
        userName : "Oppps1"
})
```

my reducer:

```
import types from './../constants/actions'

export default function userNameReducer (state = {userName : 'N/A'}, action) {
console.log('inside reducer');
switch (action.type) {
    case types.LOAD_USER_NAME:
        console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
        console.log("action.userName = " + action.userName)
        for (var k in state) {
            if (state.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                console.log("k = " + k + "; value = " + state[k]);
            }
        }
        return action.userName;
    default:
        return state
}
}
```

result in console after execution:

[image]

Comment: your reducers should be pure functions, so get rid of side effects (console.log stuff)

Comment: @IslamIbakaev thank you form recommendation but it's sovled the issue

Comment: do you mean now it woks correctly?

Comment: @IslamIbakaev -- I think they meant no, it does _not_ solve the issue -- and it's unrelated to the issue entirely.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

TLDR: stop using `combineReducers` and pass your reducer to `createStore` directly. Use `import reducer from './foo'` instead of `import * from './foo'`.

Example with default import/export, no `combineReducers`:

```
// foo.js
function reducer(state, action) { return state; }
export default reducer;

----

// index.js
import myReducer from './foo';
```

Example with `combineReducers`

```
// foo.js
export default (state, action) => { ... }

----

// bar.js
export default (state, action) => { ... } 

----

// index.js
import foo from './foo';
import bar from './bar';

const store = createStore(combineReducers({
    foo,
    bar,
});
```

The second argument of `createStore` (preloaded state) must have the same object structure as your combined reducers. `combineReducers` takes an object, and applies each reducer that is provided in the object to the corresponding state property. Now you are exporting your reducer using `export default`, which is transpiled to something like `module.exports.default = yourReducer`. When you import the reducer, you get `module.exports`, which is equal to `{default: yourReducer}`. Your preloaded state doesn't have a `default` property thus redux complains. If you use `import reducer from './blabla'` you get `module.exports.default` instead which is equal to your reducer.

Here's more info on how ES6 module system works from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

Reading [combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/UsingCombineReducers.html) docs from redux may also help.

Comment: thank you, you are absolutly right, the problem was in word `default` in my  reducer

Comment: Thank you @eugene for the explanation

Answer (score 6):

Or just:

```
import yesReducer from './yesReducer';

const store = createStore(combineReducers({
    yesReducer,
    noReducer: (state = {}) => state,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as reducers from './reducers'
```

is a good technique to avoid having your core code depend on the various functionalities implementations.

In order to make it work, you have to specify the name of the reducer to be the same as your store key **userName**. This can be achieved this way:

In the index.js that sits in the reducers folder, do

```
export { userNameReducer as userName } from "./UserNameReducer"
export { otherReducer as other } from "./OtherReducer"
```

An other way would be to directly rename the exported reducer the same as the store key.