# Unexpected key found in preLoadedState expected to find one of the known reducers keys instead

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to set the defaultState to some dummy json to create some select lists:

```
const initialState = {
    eventsHasErrored: false,
    eventsIsLoading: true,
    events: [],
    calendarView: 0,
    studentYears: [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "Year 1",
            options: ["Firm 1", "Firm 2", "Firm 3"]
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "Year 2",
            options: ["Firm 2", "Firm 3", "Firm 4"]
        },
        {
            Id: 4,
            title: "Year 3",
            options: ["Firm 5", "Firm 6", "Firm 7"]
        }
    ]
};

const reduxLogger = createLogger();

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(thunk, reduxLogger)
);
```

I get an error:

**Unexpected key studentYears found in preLoadedState expected to find one of the known reducers keys instead.**

How can I add some dummy json to my component?

```
// combineReducer
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import {
    events,
    eventsHasErrored,
    eventsIsLoading,
    calendarView
} from "./events";
import navigationReducer from "./navigationReducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    events,
    eventsHasErrored,
    eventsIsLoading,
    calendarView,
    navigationReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: Are you using combineReducer to form rootReducer. How does it look like

Comment: updated my question, thanks

Comment: I think this question has been answered here -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40053159/redux-unexpected-key-found-in-preloadedstate-argument-passed-to-createstore
Check it out

Answer (score 2):

According to the **[redux docs](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/api/createStore.md#createstorereducer-preloadedstate-enhancer)**:

> If you produced reducer with combineReducers, this must be a plain
>   object with the same shape as the keys passed to it.

So your InitialState should be like

```
    const initialState = {
        eventsHasErrored: false,
        eventsIsLoading: true,
        events: [],
        calendarView: 0,
        navigationReducer: {
          studentYears: [
              {
                  id: 1,
                  title: "Year 1",
                  options: ["Firm 1", "Firm 2", "Firm 3"]
              },
              {
                  id: 2,
                  title: "Year 2",
                  options: ["Firm 2", "Firm 3", "Firm 4"]
              },
              {
                  Id: 4,
                  title: "Year 3",
                  options: ["Firm 5", "Firm 6", "Firm 7"]
              }
          ]
        }
    };
```

Assuming `navigationReducer` contains the `studentYears` object