# Redux: where should we put initialize state for react app

Tags: reactjs, redux

For example: I want when react app is opened, it will create a redux tree with key is "user", and value is user object is parsed from LocalStorage (when user is logined).

I think I should put in `createStore`. Here is my code for creating store:

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';

import makeRootReducer from './reducers';
import { updateLocation } from './location';

export default (initialState = {}) => {
  const middleware = [thunk];
  const enhancers = [];

  let composeEnhancers = compose;
  const store = createStore(
    makeRootReducer(),
    initialState,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware), ...enhancers)
  );
  window.store = store;
  store.asyncReducers = {};

  store.unsubscribeHistory = browserHistory.listen(updateLocation(store));

  // const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);
  // console.log(history);

  return { store: store, history: null };
};
```

So as right as store is created, I initialize object:

```
 const store = createStore(
    makeRootReducer(),
    initialState,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware), ...enhancers)
  );
  store.getState().sampleString = "StackOverFlow";
```

But when my react app is started, I don't see "sampleString" key in this redux tree. Please help me figure out which part I was wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You have to dispatch some action to change the state. I think that is the only way to trigger state changes

Comment: Where is defined the initialState that you pass to that function? That variable should be holding your key. You should not be changing the state if you want it to be the initial one.

Comment: @EQuimper can you explain more detail why redux-persist can solve my problem. As I knew, redux-persist help us save redux tree to local storage.

Comment: You don't need `redux-persist` for this.

Answer (score 1):

You have exported this function:

```
export default (initialState = {}) => {
  const middleware = [thunk];
  const enhancers = [];

  let composeEnhancers = compose;
  const store = createStore(
    makeRootReducer(),
    initialState,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware), ...enhancers)
  );
  window.store = store;
  store.asyncReducers = {};

  store.unsubscribeHistory = browserHistory.listen(updateLocation(store));

  // const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);
  // console.log(history);

  return { store: store, history: null };
};
```

Let call that function `X`. You should be calling it with something like this:

```
X({sampleString: "StackOverflow"});
```

And you **MUST avoid** changing the state using assignations like this one:

```
store.getState().sampleString = "StackOverFlow";
```

Comment: thanks. I understood. Here is my code: `const initialState = window.__INITIAL_STATE__;
const { store, customHistory } = createStore(initialState);
`  when I change `const initialState = {sampleString: "StackOverFlow"}`. I meet error.

Comment: The error is: "Unexpected key "sampleString" found in previous state received by the reducer. Expected to find one of the known reducer keys instead: "location". Unexpected keys will be ignored".

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37998281/react-redux-unexpected-key-passed-to-create-store . You didn't defined your sampleString key correctly in the reducers.

Comment: I have a place in my code like this: `export const makeRootReducer = asyncReducers => {
  return combineReducers({
    location: locationReducer,
    ...asyncReducers,
  });
};
`
then I turn to:
`export const makeRootReducer = asyncReducers => {
  return combineReducers({
    location: locationReducer,
    sampleString: 'StackOverFlow',
    ...asyncReducers,
  });
};
` but redux tree doesn't reflex my custom key. thanks.

Comment: Because a string is not a reducer.